# Python- How to compare a data file .json to a log file .json and output a new file .json with changes incorporated

Tags: python, json

I have a employee file (empid, name , title) in json, and a weekly change log (empid, name , title) in json, I need to compare the two and change fields to employee and write a new file in json.

Here is what I have:
//App uses incoming .json file and a change file to perform updates and output a new .json file
//Incoming file is read into a python dictionary, change file also read into a python dictionary
//change file has 1 additional field of "rectype" ; this is used to determine the action performed for that change record - applied to that file entry of the input file; either update, append, or delete

```
# importing the module 
import json 
  
# Opening input JSON file into dictionary "inp"
with open('path/inputfilename.json') as input_file: 
    inp = json.load(input_file) 
#for dev visibility show data types    
print("Type:", type(inp))  

# Opening change JSON file into dictionary "chg"
with open('path/change_file.json') as change_file: 
    chg = json.load(change_file) 
#for dev visibility show data types
print("Type:", type(chg)) 

#loop through through change file
for c in chg

if chg{rectype(c)}='update'
then inp.update({"color": "White"})
fromkeys()
break

if chg{rectype(c)}='delete'
#delete record in inp
break

if chg{rectype(c)}='append'
#add record to inp
break
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you show what you have tried so far? Also, providing an MRE makes creating an answer much more efficient, and might also give you further insight into your problem ([How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Answer (score 0):

in a very simple way you can convert the two files to the python dictionary then work on them